# View HTML source in tree view?

Tags: html, treeview

I'd like to analyze the structure of some complex web pages that I've visited. Manually parsing out tags in the HTML source is tedious and prone to errors.

I'd like to find a utility that will accept HTML source (or a URL) as input, and show the hierarchical arrangement of the HTML elements, including source and id attributes, preferably in a treeview.

I was confident that it should be easy to find such a tool, but a few Google searches haven't turned up anything for me. I'm still confident that such a tool exists. Can the community help me find something? (I'm a Windows user and of course would prefer free if possible.)

Comment: You mean other than IE Dev Tools or Firebug?

Comment: Chrome's dev tools do this too. Just right click the page and select "inspect element" to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8+ and Chrome both have wonderful developer tools built right in. Just visit a webpage and in IE, press F12, and in Chrome, go to wrench->tools->developer tools. They both show the tree view of the page as well as let you modify it. They're both very powerful.

[image: IE9 Developer Tools]
[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have a DOM viewer built in. Firefox has a [third party extension](http://getfirebug.com/) that provides this.

These will all show the DOM after error recovery has been performed by the browser, before then you can't be sure that a valid tree *could* be constructed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use any good editor like Notepad++ which has highlighted syntax and node collapsing.

Answer (score 1):

As other have mentioned, most modern web browsers have "developer tools" built into them which include a way to browse the HTML source in a tree-view. I've put together a quick screenshot comparison of the tools that the latest versions of the top five browsers (Internet Explorer 9, Firefox 4, Chrome 12, Opera 11 and Safari 5) offer.

- **[Web Browser Developer Tools Screenshot Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojUMs.jpg)**

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug or DOMinspector addon on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Download Firefox (http://www.mozilla.org/) and install the 
Firebug addon https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/) **BOTH ARE FREE**